# Cant run Cisco Packet Tracer on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: installation, cisco, ubuntu-19.04

So i just Installed Cisco Packet Tracer 7.2.1. on my Ubuntu 19.04, so I wanted to run it but it just tells:

`aruberuto@aru-ubuntu:~$ packettracer
Starting Packet Tracer 7.2.1`

But doesn't happen anything, I figured something was wrong so i opened /opt/pt/bin and tried to open from there with ./PacketTracer7:

`aruberuto@aru-ubuntu:~$ cd /opt/pt/bin
aruberuto@aru-ubuntu:/opt/pt/bin$ ./PacketTracer7
./PacketTracer7: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

And tells me that the library libpng.so.0 doesn't exist. And i tried to install a lot of packages for trying to solve it but it tells me that libpng.so.0 cant be updated because it doesn't exist.

I need help  ;(

Answer (score 0):

I myself struggled this problem so many times and tried to solve it by installing the missing packets/libraries. There are many instructions to do so.

However this was a dead-end for me (and for most). So I found the cure by installing **Packet Tracer with Wine**. Here is the [link](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=11601).

Packet Tracer 7.2.1 still [won't work with Wine](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45980) so I installed an old version of Packet Tracer which is 6.2.0.

This is the developers' fault as they don't make the software compatible with the new libraries. Shame on Cisco.

Comment: You are correct, and the thing is, if i couldnt install ver7, i was going to install ver6. Thank u for the link, gonna try it later when im able and ill tell u how its going. Thanks!